# Get last row in last column from a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

Hello I have a csv file that contains those columns :

```
index, text , author , date
```

i want to select the last column from the last inserted row

what i did so far :

```
inputFile = 'bouyguesForum_results.csv'
f1 = open(inputFile, "r")
last_line = f1.readlines()[-1]
f1.close()
print (last_line)
```

this code gets me the last inserted row but i want to select the last column which is the date column

code output :

```
9,"J'ai souscrit Ã  un abonnement Bbox de 6â‚¬99 + 3â‚¬ de location de box, sauf que j'ai Ã©tÃ© prÃ©levÃ© de 19â‚¬99 ce mois-ci, sachant que je n'ai eu aucune consommation supplÃ©mentaire, ni d'appel, et je n'ai souscrit Ã  rien, et rien n'est prÃ©cisÃ© sur ma facture. Ce n'est pas normal, et je veux une explication.",JUSTINE,17 novembre 2021
```

thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you confusing rows with columns? Do you want to extract the date column?

Comment: Provide sample test data and the output you want.

Comment: oh yes i was confusing rows with columns sorry also i provided a code  output in post

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this: if you want the very last row

```py
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv:
    data = [[x.strip() for x in line.strip().split(',')] for line in csv.readlines()][-1][-1]
    print(data)
```

or if you want all the last elements in each row

```py
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv:
    data = [line.strip().split(',')[-1] for line in csv.readlines()]
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you got the last row, now you can just split it into a list. Sample-

```
last_line = last_line.strip("\n")
last_line = [x for x in last_line.split(",") if x!=""]
last_date = last_line[-1]
```